# ReactJS - Parse HTML tags within a String inside div and display in UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `div` in the `render()` function like below where output is a custom object

```
{output.text.split("-").map(res => 
   <div>{res}</div>                                     
)}
```

Now the `res` string may or may not have HTML elements. If it has html elements, it should be displayed accordingly in UI

For ex: if value of `res` is `Please click the link <a href="url">here</a>`, it should be displayed in the UI as below,

Please click the link [here](https://here)

Comment: That's some weird way of using React, generally you would wanna render `<div>{res}<a href="url">here</a></div>`. And if you make something up like that to work, if that `output` comes from a User-input you would **allow** them write `script`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html-react-parser library to meet you requirements.

```
import "./styles.css";
import  parse  from "html-react-parser";
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [output, setOutput] = React.useState({
    text: "test-Please click <a href='https://google.com'>here</a>"
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {output.text.split("-").map((res) => {
        return <div>{parse(res)}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `DOMParser` like this:

```
{output.text.split("-").map(res => 
   <div>{new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, "text/xml")}</div>
)}
```

For any more quires kindly do let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! DOMParser didnt work for me although I see it working in many other solutions